# Map an array with a function with two arguments - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Is it possible to map an array with a function that takes in two arguments?
Something like this:

```
let arr = [2,5,1,4,8,4]
let bankRateArr = arr.map(BankRate.init(amount:interestRate:))

class BankRate {
    let amount: Int
    let interestRate: Float

    init(amount: Int, interestRate: Float) {
        self.amount = amount
        self.interestRate = interestRate
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless `amount` and `interestRate` will both have the same value, your example is not gonna work. Of course with an array of tuples for instance it could easily work.

Comment: What are the values in `arr`?  Are they the amounts? You could use map with a fixed rate and the amount from the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass the same interest rate to all values, you can do:

```
class BankRate: CustomStringConvertible {
    let amount: Int
    let interestRate: Float
    init(amount: Int, interestRate: Float){
        self.amount = amount
        self.interestRate = interestRate
    }

    var description: String {
        return "amount: \(amount), rate: \(interestRate)"
    }
}

let arr = [2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 4]
let bankRateArr = arr.map { BankRate(amount: $0, interestRate: 0.04) }
print(bankRateArr)
```

Output:

> [amount: 2, rate: 0.04, amount: 5, rate: 0.04, amount: 1, rate: 0.04, amount: 4, rate: 0.04, amount: 8, rate: 0.04, amount: 4, rate: 0.04]

If you want each to have their own, you can do it with tuples:

```
let arr2 = [(2, 0.04), (5, 0.07), (1, 0.1), (4, 0.035), (8, 0.25), (4, 0.2)]
let bankRateArr2 = arr2.map { BankRate(amount: $0.0, interestRate: Float($0.1)) }
print(bankRateArr2)
```

Output:

> [amount: 2, rate: 0.04, amount: 5, rate: 0.07, amount: 1, rate: 0.1, amount: 4, rate: 0.035, amount: 8, rate: 0.25, amount: 4, rate: 0.2]

And thanks to Martin R, the 2nd example can be shorted a bit as:

```
let arr3: [(Int, Float)] = [(2, 0.04), (5, 0.07), (1, 0.1), (4, 0.035), (8, 0.25), (4, 0.2)]
let bankRateArr3 = arr3.map(BankRate.init)
print(bankRateArr3)
```

Comment: The code in my answer is copied directly from an Xcode 9.2 playground and it gives me no errors.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't compile as-is so make sure you copy the code from my answer.

Comment: Or `let bankRateArr2 = arr2.map(BankRate.init)` if `arr2` is defined as `[(Int, Float)]`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you will have two separate arrays

```
let amounts = [2, 5, 1, 4 ,8 ,4]
let rates: [Float] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
```

you could use

```
let bankRates = zip(amounts, rates).map(BankRate.init)
```